# maven erasing changes on code while compiling

Tags: java, maven

To compile/install the program

https://github.com/vivo-project/VIVO

using maven I run:

mvn install -e -s installer/settings.xml

I have done some small changes to the code but I noticed that my changes are deleted while this cmd is running. Is there a way to stop my changes from being deleted?

Comment: "Changes are deleted" means what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Mvn install should not remove anything.
Even in combination with clean should remove only the target folder by default.
Some IDEs does not save all or auto save. This is probably the problem.